# Show both camera capture Image and scene.background in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, ios11, arkit

In the Youtube charnel, I saw many of these demos show a portal using ARKit. Actually, I think they use Unity to build the demo. I want to use ARKit and SceneKit to implement that.

When I set the scene.background.contents property, the camera capture image couldn't show any more.

```
        if sceneView.scene.background.contents == nil {
        sceneView.scene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "Media.scnassets/environment_blur.exr")!
    }
```

in iOS 11, SCNMaterial have a new property: **colorBufferWriteMask**, but I don't know how to use it. Apple use colorBufferWriteMask to implement the **Planes Obscure Objects** in their ARKit sample code.

[image]

Does anybody have idea how to made it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to place a SCNNode in your arkit scene. You can define the node as a SCNSphere and place the image within the sphere bounds or use the essentially make the skin of the sphere your image.

Comment: I don't get that. can you please provide few lines of code